# Laravel : Client_Credentials don't work

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

In my Laravel website, I have to make a cron jobs who will retrieve some data, then update my database. 
From the docs of Laravel I thought to the machine-to-machine authentication from Laravel Passport.

So I jumped into this, installation and so on. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

I followed every single step from the docs, and from the example I found in the internet, I always got the following message

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I added the client_credentials middleware in my Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ...
    'authAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthAdmin::class,
    'client' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
];
```

Then for the basics, I created a ApiTestController with a test methods who gonna be triggered for my route.

I have put into my api.php routes this following lines :

```
/*
  Public API Routes
*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
  ... 
  Route::get('/test', 'ApiTestController@test')->middleware('client');
});
```

Basically my method just return "it works".

I have created a passport client via the `passport:client` artisan command, then use it through postman to get my Bearer token.

But it doesn't work :(

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Did you added the `auth:api` guard in the `kernel.php` for all api routes? If yes, than Passport tries to validate your *client access* token against a *user access token* which fails. You need to remove the `auth:api` guard for the routes, you want to access with your client. The `client` middleware acts as a guard in this case.

Comment: how to remove auth:api for the route?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this reply is very late however I've experienced the same issue in Passport 5.7.

To fix this issue I had to add the code below to my .htaccess. This is because I was testing in postman using https rather than http however http would return unauthenticated.

After adding the code you should be able to test your http api using an http url in postman.

Maybe it helps someone.

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```